# Is it possible to use $.post with RedirectToAction in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to asp.net, Im posting all my data to server using $.post (Jquery syntax).

Action of controller is executed @ the end I'm calling RedirectToAction to different action method, after completion of action method execution.

Eecution reaches to completed callback event of $.Post() where im loading result of request in html to root element of page. $(html).html(results).

How can i use $.post with RedirectToAction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the point of using AJAX when you replace the whole page? The whole point of AJAX is to refresh only a certain portion of the DOM. If you are going to refresh your entire page, then simply use a standard link, no need of AJAX. But if we suppose that your controller action handles 2 cases: one in which it returns a partial view and one in which it redirects, you could pass the target url as JSON:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    if (Something)
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    return Json(new { redirectTo = Url.Action("Foo", "Bar") });
}
```

and then on the client:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("SomeAction")', function(result) {
    if (result.redirectTo) {
        // the controller action passed us the url to redirect to
        window.location.href = result.redirectTo;
    } else {
        // the controller action passed us a partial result => 
        // let's update some portion of the DOM
        $('#someId').html(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can we get rid of Window.Location.href in if block, is it complusion to have completed callback method to fire up in Jquery, My question is cant we redirect to different view using RedirectToAction using $.post